# How to get the request body buffer?

Tags: node.js

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        // How to obtain the body buffer?
    }
});
```

I am aware that I can read data stream, e.g.

```
var requestBody = '';
req.on('data', function (data) {
    requestBody += data;
});
req.on('end', function () {
    console.log(requestBody);
});
```

I assume there is a way to access the data buffer directly or construct one myself?

The purpose is for forwarding an HTTP request (performing MITM for debugging purposes).

Comment: If you're asking for a way to access the underlying buffer in the `http` module implementation, I sure doubt that is possible. I even wonder why one would need to do something like that, the 'data' event should be enough.

Comment: "I assume there is a way to access the data buffer directly or construct one myself?" You construct one yourself by listening to the 'data' and 'end' events as you've noted.  There IS no "data buffer" -- the data is streaming in and the event model is how you get at that stream.

Comment: @Joe is right. As I have learned on Freenode, `req` itself it a data stream, http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html. For whatever reason, that was not obvious to me.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you, if you want, use express+bodyParser, that simple and effective, for example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:1024*1024}));

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body); //YOUR BODY
});

app.listen(8080)
```

Comment: If you are using only bodyParser, then use https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser. Thats what express is using behind the scenes.